# Making wget follow "javascript links"

Tags: wget

I'd like to mirror a webpage recursively, but it uses javascript links, such as `"javascript:readArticle(x)"`. I know that such links are simply translated into an URL, say `"/articles/read?id=x"`, can I tell wget to "translate" those links before continuing to download?

I am **not** suggesting wget should interpret javascript.

Is there a way to have wget download a page, change those links (maybe using `sed`?), then resume downloading following the new links?

Comment: Might `wget --input-file` with or without either `--force-html` or `--base` be of use to you?

Comment: I'm trying a few things in a script, but I'm having trouble remembering the "depth" of the site I'm mirroring.